# Get header value from range based on lookup value with multiple lookup values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can I get a concatenated list of 'application types' - my column headers - based on the column values being `True`?. There might be a few application types.

**Please see this:**

[image]

The objective would be to put the application type data into one column. E.g. for row 1 in the example the output would be `Application 1,Application 2`.

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Oh bummer, I just knocked up an INDEX MATCH but that only does the first `TRUE` I was going to query the 2 TRUES on project 1 but saw `There might be a few application types`. Have a go at some VBA. I like to see some coding effort before I give away an operational module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a UDF (User Defined Function) to achieve this if you are happy to use VBA. I mocked up a simple version of your setup:

[image]

The formula in cell `H2` simply takes two ranges, the current row and the headers (which need an absolute reference so that you can drag the formula down)

```
=GetHeaders(B2:F2,$B$1:$F$1)
```

To be able to use this function you will need to navigate to the VBA editor, add a new module and paste in this code:

```
Public Function GetHeaders(dataRow As Range, headers As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String, split As String

    split = ", "

    For i = 1 To dataRow.Columns.Count
        If dataRow.Cells(1, i).Value = True Then
            result = result & headers.Cells(1, i).Value & split
        End If
    Next i

    GetHeaders = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(split))
End Function
```

It's pretty straight forward, so do try to make sure you understand the code before you use it

Comment: Hi CallumDA, 

i tried it out but if i were to use the GetHeaders formula, I cannot store the macro and was unable to use sub and end sub to do it and hence, it cannot be used continuously.

Would there be a way to do this?